# Identify the html content in the Iframe based on scroll

Tags: html, iframe, scroll

I have an Iframe that contains HTML content with a div assigned to every line set. I want to capture div id of the first line in the view in Iframe based on the scroll moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something using scroll offset (`document.body.scrollTop`) combined with `elementFromPoint(x,y)`

[document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint)